# Evaluating summation of arctan function

Tags: trigonometry, summation

How should I proceed in evaluating the following:

$$
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \arctan\left(\frac{2}{r^2+r+4} \right)$$

I thought the denominator would be like: $(x+a)(x+a+2)+1$, but it didn't worked out. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint

As the denominator needs something of the form $$1+f(r)f(r+1)$$

where $f(r)=ar+b$ with $a,b$ arbitrary constants

$$\dfrac2{r^2+r+4}=\cdots=\dfrac{(r+1)/2-r/2}{1+r/2\cdot(r+1)/2}$$

Comment: Sir, if I am not wrong, then I think that in __every case__ of summation the denominator should be of the form as you've stated, in order to make difference method applicable?

Comment: @Rahul, Yes. Otherwise we can't utilize $$\arctan a-\arctan b$$